# GoLang: Working with map in Anynomous structs

Tags: go, struct, maps

I am trying to understand how to use maps in anonymous structs.

My code is as below

```golang
places := struct {
      Country map[string][]string
    }{
      make(map[string][]string)["india"] :=  []string{"Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata" }
    }
```

I tried with `new()`with initialization with no success.

is it possible to use maps inside anonymous structs ?

Thank you.

Comment: Don't use `make` or `new`, use a composite literal: `map[string][]string{"india": {"Chennai", ...}}` (note that you can *elide* the type of the elements in map [and slice and array] composite literals).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a composite literal:

```golang
places := struct {
    Country map[string][]string
}{
    Country: map[string][]string{"india": {"Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata"}},
}
```

Or, if you want to use `make`, you can do so with multiple statements:

```golang
places := struct {
    Country map[string][]string
}{
    Country: make(map[string][]string),
}
places.Country["india"] = []string{"Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata"}

// or

places := struct { Country map[string][]string }
places.Country = make(map[string][]string)
places.Country["india"] = []string{"Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata"}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work: https://goplay.space/#gfSDLS79AHB

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    places := struct {
        Country map[string][]string
    }{
        Country: map[string][]string{"india": {"Chennai", "Hyderabad", "Kolkata"}},
    }

    fmt.Println("places =", places)
}
```